# No Service Error

Tags: sms, calls

I am having trouble with my device (galaxy s4 ,model number SPH-L710, running android 4.4.2). In particular I cannot send or receive text messages or send or receive calls. I noticed that if I dial in the code *#0011# to go to Service Mode, the screen displays the message No Service at the top. Could this be related to the previous issue? And how might I fix this?

My apologies if this is an inappropriate question for this stack exchange.